# symfony2 - remove /web from urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I'm managing a website written in symfony 2.2, hosted on a web hosting service.
I'm pretty much a complete neophite in web development, so I'm probably making some stupid mistake.

Anyway, I want to be able to access the site without the /web part.
Example: 'domain.com/symfony_site/web/mypage' -> 'domain.com/symfony_site/mypage'.

Let me say from the start: I cannot manually configure apache on the server, I only have FTP access to it.
I think I'm left with .htaccess files solution.

I have tried each and everyone of the solutions I found on the internet (most of them from this site) and none worked.
And yes, mod_rewrite is enabled.

I feel like the simplest solution would be to add a .htaccess file in the root directory of the site (the one which also contains the /web folder), with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And this does seem to redirect properly, but then I get a "The requested URL web/mypage was not found on this server." if I visit 'domain.com/symfony_site/mypage'.

The desired home page 'domain.com/symfony_site' intead gives a "You don't have permission to access /symfony_site/ on this server.", so it looks like this is not even redirecting properly.

Comment: Have you tried to move the `web/app.php` file to an `index.php` file at the root of your site? (it will also require to change the paths in this file)

Comment: what if you visit `domain.com/symfony_site/mypage/web` ?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to move the `.htaccess` from the web directory to the root directory (the `DocumentRoot`).

Then, open the moved `.htaccess`, search all occurrences of `/app` and replace them by `/web/app`.
The `.htaccess` (without comments) should looks like :

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/web/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /web/app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Now your application can be correctly browsed using the project root directory as `DocumentRoot`.

This change may involve to adapt the way of loading your assets.

**NOTE:** It's a quick-and-dirty alternative assuming you cannot change the `DocumentRoot` of your application to make it points to the web directory.

Comment: This didn't work. I renamed the .htaccess in /web to _.hta (I imagine this is equivalent to deleting it), and made a file with your content in the root directory. I get 404 errors.

Comment: Is the 404 handled by Symfony or by your server ? I tried it and I can make it works, also I need to to know the exact configuration of your server in order to adapt my answer. If you can give me the full path of your application (the whole `DocumentRoot`)

Answer (score 1):

a symfony2 app is designed to have the document-root at web/

here is an example configuration for apache vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName your.domain
  DocumentRoot "/path/symfony/web"

  <Directory "/path/symfony/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

so your rewrite rule is not necessary

Comment: From the question : "Let me say from the start: I cannot manually configure apache on the server, I only have FTP access to it. I think I'm left with .htaccess files solution.". The user cannot accesses server configuration.

Comment: you should dig into something more advanced than your "consumer-hosting"